# Subviews of NSRect not affected by NSAffineTransform

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When applying an NSAffineTransform rotate and translate to an NSRect, none of the sub views are affected by the transform. I've included the code below.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
    {

        NSAffineTransform * transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
        [transform translateXBy:13.0 yBy:3.0];
        [transform rotateByDegrees:-45];
        [transform translateXBy:-13.0 yBy:3.0];
        [transform concat];


        NSImageView *imageViewWatchPointer;
        NSRect watchPointer = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 134, 49);
        imageViewWatchPointer = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:watchPointer];
        [imageViewWatchPointer setImageScaling:NSScaleNone];
        [imageViewWatchPointer setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"mastery_watch_pointer"]];
        [self addSubview:imageViewWatchPointer];

        [[NSColor blueColor] set];
        NSRectFill(watchPointer);  

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not applying `transform` to anything.  You're creating it and then throwing it away. In any case, you never add subviews in `drawRect:`. `drawRect:` is for custom-drawing the current view, not for managing the view hierarchy. The way you've done this, you're adding a new `NSImageView` every time the main view is redrawn.

I recommend going back to the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to understand how Cocoa drawing works.

Looking at your code, I don't believe you need `drawRect:` at all. You just want to add a subview, probably in `awakeFromNib` or `initWithFrame:`. I assume you want the view rotated. The easiest way to do that is to give it a backing layer (`setWantsLayer:`), and then set the `affineTransform` on the layer.

Alternately, in `drawRect:`, you could rotate the context and just draw the image itself (without using an `NSImageView`). See the Cocoa Drawing Guide for details on how to do custom drawing.